# How to call external javascript function in xsl?

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have one js file in which one function is returning value.

I want to compare this value with xml value in xsl file.

My javascript is

```
function getUser()
{
   return user;
}
```

In xsl file i want to check this value in  conditon.

How I can do that??

Comment: This isn't an XSLT question, because support for calling JS functions is not a feature of XSLT. Therefore, I have re-tagged this to "xsltprocessor". A further note is that calling extension functions in XSLT is rarely justified and should be avoided as a rule. For examle, many wanted data items that are not available in the XSLT static/dynamic context, can be provided as parameters to the transformation.

Answer (score 4):

**Although it is not standard, *it is possible to execute JavaScript functions from within your XSLT*.**

With MSXML you can use the [**`msxsl:script` extension element**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256042.aspx).

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
      xmlns:user="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace">

<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
  function getUser()
  {
   return user;
  }

</msxsl:script>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="user:getUser(.)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think you should alert to the OP that this not standar extension function implementation result in loading the script engine **every time** the function is called.

Comment: Unfortunately in this way you don't call a function on an external file; it is internal, in the .xsl.

Answer (score 2):

Refer following

1. [How To Include Client-Side Script Functions in an XSL Document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/273793)
2. [Passing parameters to javascript script in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347536/passing-parameters-to-javascript-script-in-xslt)
3. [Row value is not available in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589076/row-value-is-not-available-in-javascript)
4. [Calling Javascript within XSL after transformation in RSS Web Part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9720/calling-javascript-within-xsl-after-transformation-in-rss-web-part)

Also remember to add `DEFER` attrinute.

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" DEFER="true">
  <xsl:comment>

function hiLite()
 {
   alert("hello");
 }

</xsl:comment>
</SCRIPT>
```