# Passing parameters to javascript script in xslt

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, parameters

Is it possible to handle a parameter to a javascript function in XSLT where the script is between tags `<script type=text/javascript>....</script>.` If possible could someone give a example. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to *generate* `<script>...</script>` or to *call* a javascript function during the transformation and use the result of this call further in the transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting confused between the two things: XSLT is something that is used (in this case) to generate HTML/javascript - once that generated HTML/javascript is received by the browser then the javascript can be run.  I'm unaware of any such concept of the XSLT "passing" a variable to a javascript function.

My guess is you want something like this XSLT...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myVar = "<xsl:value-of select="XPATHVALUE"/>";
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[
    function myFunc(){
      alert(myVar);
    }
  ]]></xsl:text>
</script>
```

If you put the main "body" of the javascript within the xsl:text element, it means you won't get caught out using reserved characters (such as < > etc).

The generated HTML/javascript that is set to the browser would end up as something like this, meaning calling myFunc would display "hello world"...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myVar = "hello world";
    function myFunc(){
      alert(myVar);
    }
</script>
```

**Update**

As MichaelKey has highlighted, the <xsl:text> element above is unnecessary.  This should produce the same thing...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myVar = "<xsl:value-of select="XPATHVALUE"/>";
  <![CDATA[
    function myFunc(){
      alert(myVar);
    }
  ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the disable-output-escaping. The serializer knows it's producing a script element and should handle the content accordingly (if it doesn't, it's a bug).

Comment: I didn't realise that. I will give it a go without, but if memory serves me correctly Visual Studio (where I do all my XSLT work) starts showing formatting errors, so I wouldn't have even tried to run it

Comment: @MichaelKay As you say, the <xsl:text> element is unnecessary, but you still need to use <![CDATA[..]]> otherwise the translation attempted by .NET does not like reserved characters such as &amp;, &lt; and &gt;

Comment: Oops - didn't notice comments don't require escaping... that should be "such as &, < and >"